# How to prevent running multiple instances of setup.exe created in installshield basic msi project?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I have created my application's setup in installshield - basic MSI project...
Now when i am installing it, it allows me to run .exe multiple times simultanious...
Please let me know, how can i stop it.....

Answer (score 1):

There is already a safe guard automatically built-into Windows Installer.  If two or more of your installs actually try to install only the first one will install.  The others will throw a message saying another install is already in progress.  This is enforced by the [_msiexecute mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to gate the situation earlier, you'll have to write your own custom actions to create your own custom mutex, tear it down when the install is complete and check for it when starting the install.  However, I'd mark this problem as Functions as Designed and move on.

Comment: Can you be more specific?
How can i write mutex?
where to write code?
what should be the execution sequence?

Comment: That's too broad of a question to be able to answer. For example, first you have to pick a programming language for your custom action.  InstallScript, VBScript, C/C++, C#?  Then google that language and mutex.